# Android - how matching size of the linearlayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, pinchzoom

Hello I have a layout that can be resized but I want to synchronize 3 different linearlayout

first linearlayout as the header,second linearlayout as the leftscrollbar and the third linearlayout as the content container so the layout will be like this

```
   ____________________________
  |_____|____|HEADER___|____|__|
  |     |____|____|____|____|__|
  |_____|____|____|____|____|__|
  |     |    |    Content   |  |
  |_____|____|____|____|____|__|
  | left|____|____|____|____|__|
  |_____|    |    |    |    |  |
  |     |    |____|____|____|__|
  |_____|____|____|    |____|__|
  |     |____|____|    |____|__|
  |_____|____|____|____|____|__|
```

The header and the left scroll is scrollable and synced to the content so when I scroll the content the header and the scroll bar also scrolled. But that's a different matter and I've successfully created that. Now I want to add zoom function using pinch so I created a pinchview that detect the pinch and calculate the scale, that also done. But now I want to resize the layout using the scale I calculate from the pinch using layoutparams but when I try to zoom the layout didn't match anymore.

As you can see size of the header and the left child size is static but the size of child view of the content is dynamic so what I want to match is the width of the content cellwith the header cell width and the height of the left bar and the height of the content

this is my xml file

```
<niko.twodimensionalscroll.PinchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pvZoomContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llContainerMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llHeaderContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/llLeftBarContainer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlContainerScrollView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawingCacheQuality="low" >

                <niko.twodimensionalscroll.TwoDScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/tdScrollView"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:drawingCacheQuality="low" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llContainerSchedule"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawingCacheQuality="low"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </niko.twodimensionalscroll.TwoDScrollView>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</niko.twodimensionalscroll.PinchView>
```

I hope my question is clear enough but if you need some other information please ask in the comment and I'll explain more

Thank You

Comment: Ok put these three layouts in a relative Layout,

Comment: so change my parent view to relative layout?or change the 3 layout into relative layout?and why it can affect my code?

Comment: CHANGE PARENT OF 3 TO RELATIVE

Comment: Could you explain me how it'll affect my layout?maybe in the answer?thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#444444">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Header" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#666666"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:background="#440000">
         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="LeftBar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000099">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              android:layout_marginTop="158dp"
              android:text="Content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Try some thing like this